# Type of singularity of $a$, for which $a $ is a limit point of a sequence of zeros of the analytic function $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, singularity

Suppose $f(z)$ is an analytic function in a region $D$, and $f(z)$ is not identically equal to zero there. Let $z_n$ be a sequence of zeros of $f(z)$ in $D$. If $\lim_{n\to \infty}z_n=a$, then $a$ must be singularity of $f(z)$ (As zeros of analytic functions are isolated). I would like to classify the type of singularities that $f(z)$ can have at point $a.$

I could show that $a$ is a singularity. But I was not sure the type of the singularity. I had a part which was wrong (Saying that the singularities of Analytic function are isolated) and I took it off. Sorry if I am asking too many questions, I am new in complex analysis but I think this question was a natural and good! Thanks.

Comment: If $f$ is analytic on an open set, and there exists an acculation point of zeroes of $f$, then $f \equiv 0$ by analytic continuation.

Comment: Please correct your second sentence. There must be a typo there.

Comment: You're writing down a lot of strange things, including false statements. Please take the time to write a question that is clear and precise.

Comment: This statement is not true: *"singularities of analytic functions must be isolated"*

Comment: The conclusion that you can draw from $f$ analytic on $D$ and $a\leftarrow z_n\in D$, with $f(z_n)=0$, is that $a$ belongs to the boundary of $D$ and that it is a singular point ($f$ cannot be analytically continued to a neighborhood of $a$). Now, $f$ may or may not have an analytic continuation to a pounctured neighborhood of $a$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I made a mistake to say that part! In fact I know singularities of  meromorphic functions are isolated (not analytic), since they are poles, which was again irrelevant!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't be a removable singularity. If it was, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=0$ and therefore we could extend $f$ to an analytical function whose domain contains $a$ and, in that extension, $a$ would be a non-isolated zero. Therefore, $f$ would be the null function.

And it cannot be a pole either, because then we would have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=a\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl|f(z_n)\bigr|=+\infty,$$which is not true since, in fact, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=0$.

So, it can only be an essential singularity, such as when $f(z)=\sin\left(\frac1z\right)$.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can answer as the question is vague. At least tell us what you think the hypotheses are in your interpretation.

Comment: Can $a$ be a an non-isolated singularity for $f$ knowing that $a$ is a limit point for a sequence of zeroes of $f$?

Comment: @Parisina For the concept of singularity that I work with, all singularities are non-isolated.

Comment: You meant isolated singularities? I read in this textbook that (https://www.amazon.com/Classical-Analysis-Bartlett-Mathematics-Computer/dp/086720494X ) Removable, poles and essentials are isolated-singularities.

Comment: @Parisina Yes. Sorry. I meant isolated.